# has_many :through confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I've been looking through other questions/answers, but couldn't find anything that was helping. I have `users` and `events` and `static_events`. I now want to introduce a `schedule` for `users` to save the two different types of "events"

I'm getting hung up on organizing the associations. Specifically associating `events` and `static_events` to a specific `:foreign_key` to create the `schedule`. This is my first app, so things are still a bit new. As always, any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far:

**models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :through => :schedules, :source => "followed_id"
  has_many :static_events, :through => :schedules, :source => "followed_id"
end

class Event  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :schedules, :foreign_key => "followed_id"
end

class StaticEvent  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :schedules, :foreign_key => "followed_id"
end

class Schedule  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  has_many :events
  has_many :static_events 
end
```

**data schemas:**

```
create_table "schedules",
 t.integer   "followed_id" 
end

create_table "users",
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "events",
  t.string   "content"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  #several more fields left out for brevity
end

create_table "static_events",
  t.string   "content"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  #several more fields left out for brevity
end
```

Am I going about this in the most efficient way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. However, it's not clear why you have two different models `Event` and `StaticEvent`. In your migration it appears that they have the same fields. This seems like a good case for [single-table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance). In that scenario your `Event` model would be unchanged, but `StaticEvent` would look like this:

```
class StaticEvent < Event
  # ...
end
```

It inherits from `Event` instead of directly from `ActiveRecord::Base`. This means it gets all of `Event`'s behaviors but you can also define methods and variables specific to `StaticEvent` only.

With single-table inheritance you would have no `static_events` table, but your `events` table would have an additional string field `type`. Rails would take care of the rest.

**However**, if `StaticEvent` doesn't have any methods or variables different from `Event` except "this is a static one," and you don't think you'll have more in the future, it would make more sense to just use `Event` for both and give it an `is_static` field with a boolean type. In this case your `Schedule` model would look like this:

```
class Schedule  < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  has_many :events,        :conditions => { :is_static => false }

  has_many :static_events, :conditions => { :is_static => true },
                           :class_name => 'Event'
end
```

This way each association has its own name (`events` and `static_events`) but both refer to the same model (`:class_name => 'Event'`). The only difference is the conditions, which specify *which* `Event` records are part of that association. This also lets you do things like `Schedule.static_events.create ...` and `Schedule.static_events.where(...).first`, etc., for free.

And **finally**, you say you "now want to introduce a schedule for users to save the two different types of 'events.'" If this is your only reason for creating the `Schedule` module you should simply drop the `Schedule` model and define the above associations on `User` directly. There's no need for an extra Schedule model here unless it's going to have its own attributes and/or methods.

Comment: Jordan, my mistake - I updated the code, they do have several different fields. That being said, I think single-table inheritance is still definitely the way to go. Other than that, joining `Event` and `StaticEvent` with `User` on the same `:foreign_key` is OK and won't cause any problems?

Comment: What's the purpose of `Schedule`? Is it meant to be a class all its own or is it merely a mapping between users and the events they've saved (in which case `Scheduling` or `Attending` might be better names).

Comment: Good call, `Attending` is a much better name. It is meant to be a mapping between users and the events they've saved. But after thinking I will need to keep `Event` and `StaticEvent` as separate models as they will have too much divergent information. There is also the potential for other models that would need to be created and added to `Attending`. In light of this, would my original code/logic still be appropriate, granted the name change of `Schedule` to `Attending`?

Comment: In this case `Attending` would be a join model in a `has_many :through` relation. It would have two columns, `user_id` and `event_id`. Your `User` model is essentially correct. For each event that a User "follows" a new record will be created in `attendings` with the User's id and the Event's id. The [Association Basics Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) has a good section on this that maps closely to what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Jordan. I appreciate it and have a much better understanding going forward.